# Replacing one of the repeated words

Tags: text-processing

Hi Im new to this so please bear with me. I have a .txt file where I want to replace a word but the problem is, that word is being repeated over and over again (lets assume you have million of lines like this)

```
TOPIC:
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
BANANA
```

I want to replace the first occurence of Apple to Mango like this

```
TOPIC:
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
BANANA
```

Is there a way to do this through sed or awk specifically(from what I understand sed can be used to replace words but not multiple lines of inputs - in my case I just want to replace the very first word) btw if its doable through other tools thats fine as well

Comment: it looks like it should be a yaml file, isn't it? are you trying to do this on a yaml file?

Comment: No its just a normal .txt file - I'm basically trying to find a specific word and replace it with another word in a file that has other repeating words

Comment: I reverted to your original question. Please don't radically alter questions after answers have been posted. You can instead ask a new question, but make sure to explain what you need accurately so we can understand. Ideally, show us a few lines of your _actual_ input and the output you want from that. For example, can we assume that the word `TOPIC` will be present? If not, we need to know this so we don't rely on it.

Comment: @terdon Apologies again. Im new to this so I'm not sure how the edits and asnwers works. Thanks for reverting it back!

Comment: Don't worry about it, there's no reason to apologize! Our rules are weird, we know and we don't expect new users to magically get them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$0=="APPLE" && !done++{ $0="MANGO" } 1' file
TOPIC:
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
BANANA
```

Comment: @Geralt  Scripts need testing. Config-type files are too variant (order, spacing, optionality). For a few files, I would use a visual editor. For a large number, I would write a script and test it against as many hard cases as I could find. Never write a five-line script for a two-line edit. And always get a backup. I usually `diff` to prove I didn't change anything I didn't intend.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed` and assuming that there's always going to be a first line saying something other than `APPLE`:

```bsh
sed '1,/APPLE/ s/APPLE/MANGO/' file
```

This matches the lines from line 1 to the next line that contains the substring `APPLE`.  On those lines, it substitutes the substring `APPLE` with `MANGO`.  The effect is that the first occurrence of `APPLE` *after the first line* is replaced with `MANGO`.

With GNU `sed` you could use

```bsh
sed '0,/APPLE/ s/APPLE/MANGO/' file
```

which would also cover the first line in case that contained the substring `APPLE`.

---

With `awk`:

```bsh
awk '!found && /APPLE/ { sub("APPLE", "MANGO"); found = 1 }; 1' file
```

This tries to find the substring `APPLE` on each line, and when it has been found, the `sub()` call replaces the substring with `MANGO`.  A flag variable, `found`, is then set to 1 (a boolean *true* value) to stop the substitution from happening again.  Each line, modified or not, is printed unconditionally.

---

Using `ed`:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '/APPLE/ s//MANGO/' ,p Q | ed -s file
```

This search for a line containing the substring `APPLE`.  When found, it substitutes that substring with `MANGO`.  Only the first match in the file is handled.

The editing script

```
/APPLE/ s//MANGO/
,p
Q
```

performs the search and the substitution, prints the whole editing buffer to standard output, and then quits unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ = "MANGO" if m?APPLE?' file
```

Result:-

```
TOPIC:
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
BANANA
```

Using POSIX sed constructs we can also do as follows:

```
sed -e '
  1{x;s/^/MANGO/;x;}
  /APPLE/!b
  G
  /\n$/{P;d;}
  z;x
' file
```

Replace `z`with `s/.*//` for POSIX sed.